# Best way to save a data structure with date-related varying attributes in Swift/CoreData

Tags: swift, data-structures, core-data, dynamic-data

I am thinking about how to best represent a certain data structure efficiently in Swift using CoreData. What I need is work with accounts (like savings, earning etc.). So what would probably make sense is an account class, where each account instance might have multiple characteristics like e.g. `ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID` which do not change. The core however is the `VALUE` attribute, which would hold the value of the account at a certain point in time. The complex thing here is that this value obviously might change over time (lets say on a daily basis, abstracting for intra-day changes) and I would need to be able to get the value of each instance for any given date. E.g. I might have my `savings_private` for which I would want to get the value at each month-end. This value might have changed, but as well could stay the same for various days/months. How could this most efficiently (when it comes to used space but - and that is even more important - be able to access computationally efficient) be done with a CoreData Entity/Class? I was thinking about maybe always starting with zero and then only somehow save the changes plus the date of change and then have some method for the call which would add all changes up to a date parameter - but was curious about what a best-practice might be here, as I guess I am not the first one trying to solve this.

Comment: If you have an account entity then you should also have a transaction entity to track what happens with the account. So then you could either calculate an end of month balance on the fly using the transactions or perhaps it can be worthwhile to have some kind of statistics entity where you store such calculated values